# Laravel Get Old Value Inside Looping Input Fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have some form inputs that require validation. I want to get the old value inside these looping input fields.

```
@foreach ($periods as $key=>$value)
    @if (date('D', strtotime($value)) == 'Sun')
        @php continue; @endphp
    @endif
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="{{ $employee->id }} presence-value form-control" name="row[{{$key}}][presence_value]" required>
                <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
                <option value="1" {{ 1 == old('row['.$key.'][presence_value]') ? 'selected' : '' }}>(1) Penuh Hari</option>
                <option value="0.5" {{ 0.5 == old('row['.$key.'][presence_value]') ? 'selected' : '' }}>(0,5) Paruh Hari</option>
                <option value="0" {{ 0 == old('row['.$key.'][presence_value]') ? 'selected' : '' }}>(0)Tidak Masuk</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <input type="hidden" class="{{ $employee->id }} presence-date" name="row[{{$key}}][presence_date]" value="{{ $errors->any() ? old('row['.$key.'][presence_date]') : $value }}">
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the old value with `old` helper only if it is stored in session.

Can you explain what is the row? Is it a php variable or something else?

```
row[{{$key}}][presence_value]
```

Comment: It'd improve your answer if you provided some code to help the TO achieve this.